# Trap XAML trigger event from code behind

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have a very simple DataTemplate Trigger and I need to catch it from code behind when is  raised. I seen this example: http://geekswithblogs.net/mrnat/archive/2007/09/20/115472.aspx, but i don't know how to make working it with my DataTrigger. This is my code:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="PASS">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Name="LblWarn" Content="{Binding DescWarning}" FontSize="11" Style="{StaticResource FormLabel}"/>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ID_Warning}" Value="1">
                    <Setter TargetName="LblWarn" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource FormLabel}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>

        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no, no... forget that terrible idea. Had you provided even minimal details on what your *actual* goal was, then I could have provided you with a better answer. As it is and going by what little description you added, all I can do is to talk you through a sensible way of getting the same result.

So first, your `DataTrigger` is `Binding` to the `ID_Warning` property of some class and reacting when the value of this property is equal to `1`. So you basically want to know when the `ID_Warning` property  has a value of `1`.  This is the way that this should be done (in the class that defines the property):

```
public string ID_Warning
{
    get { return iD_Warning; }
    set
    {
        iD_Warning == value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ID_Warning");
        if (iD_Warning == 1)
        {
            DoSomethingHere();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need access to this from a view model or other class that has one or more instances of this class declared in it, then you can simply use a `delegate` or event to pass the information up.